# Hadoop: what will happen when remove folder under /tmp/logs/hive/logs/hive

Tags: hadoop, hive

CDH ver 5.3 install from Cloudera Manager.

My cluster using hive,and Other service setting is like this:
`・yarn.nodemanager.remote-app-log-dir=/tmp/logs
・yarn.nodemanager.remote-app-log-dir-suffix=logs
・replication setting is 2`

I have an trouble removing folder under `/tmp/logs/hive/logs/`.
Especially`/tmp/logs/hive/logs/hive`

I tried to delete `/tmp/logs/hive/logs/hive/xxxxxxx.xxxxxxx` by using hdfs commands ,but folder size is too big to remove.

even `hadoop fs -ls /tmp/logs/hive/logs/hive/` did not work...(there was no answer from hdfs.(size is almost 3TB))

So instead, I decided to use [Hadoop fs -rmr /tmp/logs/hive/logs/hive/*]. But, I have no idea what will happen to my cluster if I use this command(I worry about somewhere will not able to be accessed, because of this  ).

Is there any problem? Or have a good idea to deal with this problem (I don't want to reboot my cluster).

Comment: My 5 cents: probably you need to add `-skipThrash` option to the rmr command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HDFS directory `/tmp/logs` is the default location used for Mapreduce **log aggregation**; there is another *critical* property which is...

> `yarn.log-aggregation.retain-seconds`: How long to wait before
>   deleting aggregated-logs, ***-1 or a negative number disables the
>   deletion of aggregated logs***.
> One needs to be careful and not set
>   this to a too small a value so as to not burden the distributed
>   file-system.

*https://fr.hortonworks.com/blog/simplifying-user-logs-management-and-access-in-yarn/*

A typical cluster purges MR logs after 5 to 30 days, depending on activity (and maybe compliance requirements). If you never purge anything, then you are bound to hit a wall sooner or later...!

---

OK, if you really need to manually purge that stuff *en masse*, you can do it. It's a bit ridiculous to switch brutally from purge-nothing no purge-everything, but anyway.

For the blog post above, you can note that `/tmp/logs` must have access privileges set to 1777 i.e. *"user read/write/execute, 
group read/write/execute, other read/write/execute, and sticky bit set"* (just like `/tmp`); and also its group ownership must match the primary group of the service account running NodeManager services.

In other words: anyone can create a sub-directory there; the sticky bit and group ownership tricks mean that both YARN and the creator can read/write/purge the logs files inside -- but no-one else.

Now the interesting part is that a new user launching its first MapReduce job will automatically create a new sub-dir named after him/her, plus a `logs/` sub-sub-dir; and the first query that was ever run by HiveServer2 under `hive` service account created automatically the `hive/` and `hive/logs/` subdirs.
=> If you delete these subdirs, then they will be recreated automatically on the next run
=> but if you delete them ***while*** a HS2 session is running a query, then that query will probably crash and burn when trying to push its logs on HDFS!

Comment: Thank you for answering! So,I decided not to execute above commands. I gonna find another way to reduce amount of data size.